# SharePoint 2007/2010 Custom Access Request Page

Tags: 2007, development

Does anyone know were to start to create a custom Access Request Page or how to modify the default behavior.

We would like to use our own workflow behind the Access Approval for a specific site collection:

- e-mail send to specific owner that a user is waiting for approval
- a list item with the user and some info(e-mail) is created in a requests for access list (State=new)
- Approver gives/denies the access through AD (manual action)
- Changes the status of the list item entry for the request (State=Approved  or Denied)
- Based on the status (State) a mail template is send to the user

Thanks in advance for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a good link for this:
http://soderlind.no/archives/2010/05/26/customize-out-of-the-box-application-pages-accessdenied-confirmation-error-login-requestaccess-signout-webdeleted/

In SP 2010 no httpmodules are needed any longer!

Answer (score 1):

Off hand I don't know of a way to tap into this.  Unfortunately, most likely this is a job for a httpmodule.  In your module test for the access request page url for the site you are looking for and then redirect to your custom application page that does everything you want it to do.